# Difference between subclass and element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A = { 1 , 2 , B } be a set
Let C = { 1 , 2 } be a set

Now I can state that B is an element of A.

Also with the deffination of subclass:
C is subset of A as for all x belongs to C, x belongs to A.

Now can I ask if B is subclass/subset of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the answer is **no**: $B$ is an element of $A$, not a subset...

...however if, for example, $B=C=\{1,2\}$, then $B$ is both a subset and an element of $A$.

On the other hand (the "more usual" case) if for example $B=\{2,3,4\}$ then $B$ is not a subset of $A$, thought it is still an element of $A$.